# Max resolution for processing with GD

Tags: php, gd

I have an applicaton to generate images at 600 DPI with 1000*360, so i need an image with 6000*2160 at 72DPI, when i try to create image with this much resolution GD is not working.
Can some one tell me the reason,? or do we have any limitation in processing resolution in GD?

Comment: running out of memory?

Comment: @DevZer0 : how to know that?

Comment: http://alexrabe.de/2008/05/13/understand-gd-library/

Comment: so how to get over this issue? if it is memory one?

Answer (score 1):

As @DevZer0 mentioned, it seems like a memory problem.

To bypass memory limit, try setting it as infinite with the following command in PHP at the top of your code:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Imagemagick as another option, if your GD library doesn't work.

To create such image you can use "resample" option. Please get more info from the below site.

> http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resample